# How do I create numerous outputs for a string that contains several possible characters within a "[]" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and am still learning.  If I have a string that contains several possible characters within `[]`, how do I create and output that spits out all possible values?  For example, let's say my string is `"ABC[XY]123"`, where the possible outputs are either `"ABCX123"` or `"ABCY123"`.  I want to create a script that prints both of those possibilities from the original input of `"ABC[XY]123"`.  I am aware of the fact that this is not a list, but a string.  Does it make sense to turn the string in to a list first as well?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question). If you get stuck at a specific issue, you can ask here.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't convert the whole string to a list of chars. The chars inside a `[]` should be all in one list item. Then there is `itertools.product` for the rest.

Comment: Use a regex to detect strings inside `[` and `]` characters then use `itertools` to generate all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

So accroding to your comment, only one char in `[chars]` can be chosen out in every output. Then the problem is much easier, just match the `chars` in `[chars]` and replace it with every char in `chars` in a `for` loop:
    import re

```
string = input('')
chars = re.search(r'\[(.*)\]',string).group(1)
for char in chars:
    repl_string = re.sub(r'\[.*\]',char,string)
    print(repl_string)
```

Input:

> ABC[XY]123

Output:

> ABCX123 ABCY123

Comment: Thank you for answering c.k.  I was looking to do something a little different though.  I am only interested in receiving two outputs: "ABCX123" and "ABCY123".  Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @Mike Well it's my fault to misunderstand your question, I've already edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much c.k. It’s a very clear explanation.